# ListView in an ExpansionPanel/ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a few long lists and want to display everything on screen. Because it isn't organised I want to create an `ExpansionTile` so the user can open and close the desired list. I'm only not able to create this the way I want to. I can open my `ExpansionTile` but I can't scroll down to view the numbers on the bottom. Can I use `ExpansionTile` in this case or does an other Widget do the job better?

Following is a simplified version of my code:

```
void main() async {
  runApp(ExpansionTileDemo());
}


class ExpansionTileDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExpansionTileDemoState createState() => _ExpansionTileDemoState();
}

class _ExpansionTileDemoState extends State<ExpansionTileDemo> {
  List<int> numbers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      numbers.add(i);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("ExpansionTile demo"),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            ExpansionTile(
              title: Text('List 1'),
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: numbers.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      "${numbers[index]}",
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            ExpansionTile(
              title: Text('List 2'),
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: numbers.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      print(numbers[index]);
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          "${numbers[index]}",
                        ),
                      );
                    })
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set shrinkWrap as true in the list view given to body.See if that's works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: instead of using a `ListView` a `Column` does the job.

So the code will be the following:

```
void main() async {
  runApp(ExpansionTileDemo());
}

class ExpansionTileDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExpansionTileDemoState createState() => _ExpansionTileDemoState();
}

class _ExpansionTileDemoState extends State<ExpansionTileDemo> {
  List<int> numbers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      numbers.add(i);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("ExpansionTile demo"),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          
          children: [
            ExpansionTile(
              title: Text('Numbers'),
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    for (int i in numbers)
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text("$i"),
                      )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            ExpansionTile(
              title: Text('Numbers'),
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    for (int i in numbers)
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text("$i"),
                      )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```